# Need to find crash while running the IOS automation script

Tags: javascript, ios

I am using instruments for testing IOS apps. Is there any way to find about the application crash while my script is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should still be a crashlog produced that you can fetch with Organizer. Also it is always a good idea to use some more advanced crash reporting tool anyway, like HockeyApp and QuincyKit. It comes with the added advantage of automatic symbolication, crash grouping and analysis.

Comment: Im a tester. I use to write scripts for automating the application. Is there any way to capture the log in our automation scripts.

Comment: the built in automation doesn't support that, but crashlogs are still produced on the device and can be fetched later. Other automation frameworks like phonemonkey are similarly unlikely to survive a crash in the application they host.